# How do I show an impulse response leads to a zero-phase frequency response?

Tags: filters, impulse-response, linear-phase

I'm trying to understand how to show that with real coefficients, the phase response of a filter is 0. Here is the impulse response

$h[n] = b_1d[n+1] + b_0d[n] + b_1d[n-1]$

How should I approach showing this?

Comment: Hint: look at the symmetry properties of the Fourier Transform, e.g. http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/340/ft_symmetry.php

Answer (score 1):

1) Define $d[n]$ as a sinusoidal

2) Apply angle addition formulas

3) Simplify

4) Interpret the results

Hope this isn't too much.   Sounds like a homework problem.

Ced

Comment: I'm not sure I expressed myself correctly. h[n] is the impulse response, and so d[n] I'm pretty sure represents impulses ala [1,0,0,...]. I'm supposed to show that it leads to a zero-phase FR when (b0,b1) \in R^2.

Comment: @user34931, These two links should help:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_response and https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/536.

Comment: @user34931, Is this a homework problem or are you trying to learn this stuff on your own?  Major hint from the dsp link:  "For discrete-time systems, this is possible, because you can write any signal x[n] as a sum of scaled and time-shifted Kronecker delta functions:"

$$ x[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x[k] \delta[n - k] $$

From the Wiki article:  "It is a measure of magnitude and phase of the output as a function of frequency, in comparison to the input."  You are asking about the phase.  Here is a question and my answer about the magnitude:  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46510.

Comment: Yea this is a homework problem I'm trying to tackle.

I understand what an impulse response is, in that a bunch of impulses with scalars, each delayed by different numbers of samples, is essentially an LTI system, (in this case a filter).

The part that confuses me is how knowing that this impulse response has a non phase-shifted response. Is it because the IR is symmetrical?

Comment: @user34931, I suggest you follow my recipe in my answer and see how far you get.  Once you have accomplished that, apply the same approach to this definition:

$$ h[n] = b1*d[n] + b0*d[n-1] + b1*d[n-2] $$

Notice that the phase lag is not zero in this case.  Then do a search on "Finite Impulse Response filter with symmetric coefficients"

Comment: @user34931, In the "Estimation and plotting" section of the Wiki article, the second bullet point is:  "sweeping a constant-amplitude pure tone through the bandwidth of interest and measuring the output level and phase shift relative to the input"  That is what the steps I outlined is conceptually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Given an impulse response of the form $h[n]$ for an LTI system, a zero phase freqency response means that the DTFT (discrete-time Fourier transform) 
$$H(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h[n]e^{-j\omega n} $$ is **real and positive**.

If it's real but negative, then that's an easily avoidable $\pi$ phase shift and if it's not real but complex then its either linear phase or nonlinear phase...